# Ruby Sum of Integers for Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: ruby, recursion, fibonacci

I've searched Stack Overflow and haven't found my question, so I think this will be safe to post. I'm working on a standard piece of code that prints the first 10 integers of the Fibonacci sequence, and then adds those first 10 integers together and prints the sum. The code I have written essentially works, but I'm trying to combine the map and inject methods at the bottom to make the code more efficient. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
  def fib(n)
      return 1 if n <= 2

      fib_index = 3
      a, b = 1, 1

      while fib_index <= n
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        fib_index += 1
      end
    c
  end

p (1..10).map {|i| fib(i)}
p (1..10).inject {|sum, i| sum + fib(i)}
```

I am also interested in a method that uses recursion:

```
 def fibonacci( n )
    return  n  if n <= 1
    fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 )
  end
  p ( 1..10 ).map {|i| fibonacci(i)}
  p ( 1..10 ).inject {|sum, i| sum + fibonacci(i)}
```

Comment: I see no purpose in showing your recursive alternative. The question is not about computing the sequence, it's about summing their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts "Total: %i" %
  ((1..10).inject(0) do |t,i|
    f = fib(i)
    puts "%s: %s" % [i.to_s.rjust(2), f.to_s.rjust(3)]
    t + f
  end)
 1:   1
 2:   1
 3:   2
 4:   3
 5:   5
 6:   8
 7:  13
 8:  21
 9:  34
10:  55
Total: 143
```

Comment: Expected output should be `143` I believe.

Comment: Thanks, @sagarpandya82. Fixed it.

Comment: That indeed produces the sum. I am, however, trying to print the sequence of the first ten integers of Fibonacci, as well as the the sum of the first ten integers. So: `0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 143` (143 being the sum).

Comment: @StephenRoss try using `tap` like `(1..10).map {|i| fib(i)}.tap{|f| print f.join(', '); print ('. Sum: ') }.inject(:+)` will return: `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55. Sum: 143`

Comment: Stephen, I fixed it to print both.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. I added your code to what I had wrote and this definitely works.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I tried your solution and this worked as well. Thanks.